# How to sort groups of rows with a parent within an Ant table?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I'm using react and ant design to build my table. The table has rows which should preserve some grouping relative to their parent row. For example, this data...

```
const data = [
    {id: 0, label: "Parent Item 1", cost: 2, parentId: null, isParent: true}, 
    {id: 1, label: "Child Item 1", cost: 1, parentId: 0, isParent: false},
    {id: 2, label: "Child Item 2", cost: 1, parentId: 0, isParent: false},
    {id: 3, label: "Parent Item 2", cost 1, parentId: null, isParent: true}, 
    {id: 4, label: "Child Item 1", cost 1, parentId: 3, isParent: false}, 
]
```

...should render a table like this:

```markdown
| id | label         | cost |
|----|---------------|------|
| 0  | Parent Item 1 | 2    |
| 1  | Child Item 1  | 1    |
| 2  | Child Item 2  | 1    |
| 3  | Parent Item 2 | 1.5  |
| 4  | Child Item 1  | 1.5  |
```

However, the child items should always be below their parent. When sorting the table, it should only sort on the parent's data, ignoring children and keeping the child's position below its parent.

For example, if I sort on "Cost" (lowest-to-highest) for the table above, it should sort the rows like this:

```markdown
| id | label         | cost |
|----|---------------|------|
| 3  | Parent Item 2 | 1.5  |
| 4  | Child Item 1  | 1.5  |
| 0  | Parent Item 1 | 2    |
| 1  | Child Item 1  | 1    |
| 2  | Child Item 2  | 1    |
```

Notice how the sorting only happened on the parent rows. And the child rows kept their position relative to their parent.

I think I can use a sort function like this to only target the parent rows. But I'm not sure how to handle the child rows.

```js
 {sorter: (a, b) => {
   if(a.isParent && b.isParent){
     return a.cost - b.cost;
   } else {
     // one or more rows is child, not sure what to do here...
   }
 }}
```

The answer must be a function passed to Array.prototype.sort(). Where the only variables to work with are two rows `sort(a, b => {})`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two split sorts. But be careful with embedded loop if you have a lot of elements.

```
const parents = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.isParent) {
    acc.push({
      parent: item,
      children: data.filter(it => // here you should determine is child of certain parent or not)
                    .sort((it) => // sort by cost)
    })
  }

 return acc;
}, [])

const sortedParents = parents.sort(({parent}) => // sort parents by cost)
```

Comment: This would work, however, the solution must be a function passed to Array.prototype.sort(a, b)